# Quality Recommendation/Subjective Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion

Let's try to nail this down and get some consensus on these questions and move forward.  I've definitely got some thoughts of my own, but I'd love to hear everyone else's.

For reference, if you mouse over the up/down arrows you'll get the standard guidance for all stackexchange sites.

- **Questions**

  - **Up** - This question is useful and clear
  - **Down** - This question is unclear or not useful
- **Answers**

  - **Up** - This answer is useful
  - **Down** - This answer is not useful

Comment: Hi Pat. What's this question/discussion aimed at? It looks like it's in response to other meta discussions - if so could you point to a couple?  Or are you avoiding that deliberately to try to start from a clean slate?

Comment: Are you talking about outlines towards subjective answers/questions? If so, this is a great guideline: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/